# Core Data: when is deleteObject: done?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a problem using a core data model in a table view. In the table view's commitEditingStyle: delegate method I first delete the model's object and then the corresponding row in the table view, similar to this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self coreDataObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

But this raises an NSInternalInconsistencyException in the UITableView because the numberOfRowsInSection: delegate method return the wrong number of rows since the Core Data object hasn't been deleted yet.

How do I fix this "the official way"? Or the best way?

1. Do I have to track the NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification notification and wait for the corresponding delete notification? It's doable, but can quiclky get quite messy.
2. Do I just wait and hope it's been deleted after a while? I have tested inserting a [self performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:] to delay the deletion of the table view row. And it works even with 0.0 delay. I presume the Core Data framework deletes the object after the current run loop has finished, but is this guaranteed? It could just as well just be pure coincidence.
3. Is the some other way to handle the situation? Would have been nice with a block completion API like deleteObject: withCompletionHandler:.

Any ideas?

/ Påhl

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming are you using `FetchedResultsController` to fill your table with the core data objects. So the idea is that you need to implement the following method.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
}
```

And in `commitEditingStyle:` you just delete the object from `managedObjectContext` and let the `didChangeObject` delegate handle the table modifications for you.

Example implementation for `didChangeObject` can be found here:
[Apple's document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using a FetchedResultController. It's for an iPad app and I have to use a normal UITableView. The core  data objects are already fetched before.

Comment: Well the convention is to use `FetchedResultsConttroller` to respond to object changes in a `UITableView`. From the documentation: "An instance of NSFetchedResultsController uses methods in this protocol to notify its delegate that the controller’s fetch results have been changed due to an add, remove, move, or update operations."

Comment: Very convenient! But it doesn't help me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have solved the problem by yourself, however the issue in your code is that are missing the part where you 'delete' the object from the datasource.
In

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
```

you have to put:

```
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // delete obj from the context
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self coreDataObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // REMOVE obj from the dataSource (dataSource is your NSArray or NSMutableArray where are stored the objects
    [dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // then refresh the tableView
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I don't use a NSMutableArray in my data source. My model classes are custom core data classes, i.e. the number of rows in the table view is asked in the data source delegate method numberOfRowsInSection: and at that time I need the core data stack to have deleted the object otherwise my model will answer with the wrong number of rows. Or in other words, I need to refresh the table view with deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:: when I know the object have been deleted from the managed object context. So it's crucial to know exactly when that happens.

Comment: Sorry, but from where you read the number of rows?
How suggest @dombesz, or you have an nsfetchedresultcontroller or you have an a structure where the tableView dataSource methods can know the number of its table rows.
Can you post please, for example, the `numberOfRowsInSection` method code?

Comment: I read the number of rows from my model class. My model classes are the core data classes themselves (customized). So I don't have a data structure for the table view, nor do I use the NSFetchedResultController since this would not work in my case. I use the model classes all over the app and the objects are usually fetched before I present the table view. The code for numberOfRowsInSection is simply:

`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  
{  
  return actionList_.actions.count;  
}`

Comment: Ok. I think that your solution is not the best approach. However you can send a message, like a `[NSNotification postNotification]` with the indexPath, to your model class. Then in the method that receive the message you can simply delete the object(and check with the `isDelete` the result), save the context, and then call the `[tableView reloadData]` method. For use the reloadData, that isn't in the model, you can use another `[NSNotification postNotification]` from the Model Class or add a Listener to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` in the Class which manage the tableView.